# How do I move a live website to my local machine with mamp

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am trying to move a site from a live URL to my local MAMP environment. How could I do this as I am having a real pain in the back side doing this as wp-admin keeps on redirecting me to my live site or saying certain pages don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already copied your entire WordPress directory from your web server to your local MAMP folder.

To take care of the database and URLs, I find it easiest to export the entire DB from your web server using phpMyAdmin or similar, then run find and replace on the exported SQL file to replace your old url (http://www.yourwebsite.com/) with your MAMP url (http://localhost:8888/yourwebsite) then run the SQL script to install the database locally (I use SequelPro).

Comment: Here is the SQL query to do the URL replacement. Change as appropriate.
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');

Answer (score 1):

[There is a great tutorial.](http://www.craniumstorm.com/how-to-move-a-wordpress-site/)
It's not enoght just modify the wp-config.php. You have to change all URL in the database too.

Comment: The link to the "great tutorial" is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit wp-config.php (in root dir) and add/modify these lines:

```
$ntz_site_url = 'http://localhost:8888/';

define('WP_SITEURL', $ntz_site_url);
define('WP_HOME', $ntz_site_url);
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', $ntz_site_url.'/wp-content');
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', $ntz_site_url.'/wp-content/plugins');
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open up your wp-login.php file, check if there is some option update:

  update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
  update_option('home','http://example.com');
- Remove those lines, or update the addresses. Maybe this is the cause of your headaches, because it may update your database siteurl and home options everytime you access the login page.