# Failed to run wordpress website on local machine, it gets redirected to live website

Tags: wordpress

**What I want to do** > I need to run a version of my live website on my local machine.

**Why I need to run it on local machine** I need to edit the website on my local machine and when everything is perfect copy it onto server. So I can easily make changes to the website without scaring of breaking the live website.

**Whats the problem** > I could run it on my local machine but when I log in to wordpress from localhost it redirects me to the live server.

**What steps did I followed** > I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240417/how-do-i-move-a-live-website-to-my-local-machine-with-mamp), installed mamp and downloaded whole wordpress directory to htdocs directory of mamp, then exported the database on server and imported it to my local server. Ran the server, entered username and password and was redirects to the live server rather than running the website on my local machine.

Comment: I am not a Wordpress developer but got tired of pulling my hair out with MAMP. I switched to using Homestead by Laravel, an implementation of Vagrant - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead. Makes it so much easier to work on development sites!

Comment: what are the advantages? MAMP is easy just two clicks to run.

Comment: Homestead gives you a virtual machine with everything all set - Ubuntu, PHP, HHVM, Nginx, MySQL, etc. When I want to add a new development site I map its directory to the Homestead config file, edit my computer's Host file, and run `vagrant up` in the command line. No surprises, consistent every time. It's well documented on the link I posted, worth a shot.

Comment: I found it easier than MAMP in the long run when it came to working with several sites, databases, etc. I kept screwing something up in MAMP or Apache settings, Vagrant (and thus Homestead) lets me just destroy the virtual box if I break something and start anew. If you do give it a shot, when you access your dev site be sure to append port 8000 to the URL - for example, http://mysite.app:8000

Answer (score 0):

The code is the same, you just have to edit the database configuration of localhost and change domain to `localhost`.

Comment: where should I do it? on which file?

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr:

run this to fix it: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

### long answer:

Most importantly, the "Home URL" and "Site URL" on the `Settings -> General` need to be changed. Also, many other URLs are saved into the Database including the domain name. Since some of them might be php-serialized, just search/replace in the database might screw up some things.

The [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) has lots of info on moving / clonign a site. Still, the easiest way is the tool from tl;dr above.