# Moving LAMP project from external machine to local

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, devops, web-hosting, lamp

I can’t really understand how to move files of my website (lamp + Wordpress) from lamp stack on my external virtual machine to the local. I would be really glad if someone could explain me the steps.

I’ve tried everything from google, but you can always send me a link where I haven’t been already.

Comment: I think post is trying to do the same thing as you. Have you tried it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643245/failed-to-run-wordpress-website-on-local-machine-it-gets-redirected-to-live-web?rq=2